# Short form for expression <label>

Tags: html

This works fine:

```
<label>myText</mytext>
```

Is it possible to have short form? This doesn't work:

```
<label myText>
```

Comment: And why do you want to do that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying is an Invalid HTML. As per [W3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html#label-tags)

> A label element must have both a start tag and an end tag.

So you need to write that in the lengthy way if you are going with traditional HTML. If you use some templating lib / Pre-Processor than it might give you additional features which will further let you write compact/tighter syntax.

For example you can use HAML, Slim and so on..

If we take [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/) as an example here, all you need to write is

```
label Username
```

This will further compile to .. [Demo](http://codepen.io/mr_alien/pen/YybzOq) *(Click on compile please)*

```
<label>Username</label>
```

Further if you want to add attributes to your `label`

```
label for='username' Username
```

Will compile to

```
<label for="username">Username</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know only one shorting:

```
<!-- from large -->
<label for="foo">Question:</label>
<input id="foo" value="answer" />

<!-- shorten me -->
<label>Question:
       <input value="answer" />
</label>
```